# Append to text inside XML tag

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I am trying to figure out a way to **append to a string within an XML Tag using ElementTree.**

Basically I want to produce:

```
<gco:CharacterString>

2016-08-11 13:52:15  -  Bob Smith
fourth comment yadayada

2016-08-11 13:53:34  -  Bob Smith
third comment blah

2016-10-17 11:13:41  -  Bob Smith
second comment

2016-10-25 10:53:19  -  Bob Smith
first comment

</gco:CharacterString>
```

And each time a user goes in to enter a comment it will append it and date stamp it.

I normally build a tag like this:

```
historystrings = ET.SubElement(statement,"
{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco}CharacterString").text = (datestamp,comment)  # SOURCE HERE
```

But not sure how to append using Element Tree so that it **keeps a record of previous entries.**

Comment: Aside: the data you are adding is structured. It might be better to maintain that structure in the XML, for example, `<comment><date>2016-08-11 13:52:15</date><author>Bob Smith</author><text>yada</text></comment>`

Comment: I have considered it but unfortunately I need to stay with this format due to legacy formatting.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to gain access to the existing element somehow. For example, like so:

```
gco_cs = root.find('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco}CharacterString')
```

Then you can modify the `.text` attribute, like so:

```
gco_cs.text += '\nSome new data\n'
```

Here is a complete example:

#### foo.py

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('foo.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

gco_cs = root.find('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco}CharacterString')
gco_cs.text += '\nSome new data\n'

ET.dump(root)
```

#### foo.xml

```xml
<foo xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco">
<gco:CharacterString>
some text
</gco:CharacterString>
</foo>
```

#### Result:

```
$ python foo.py 
<foo xmlns:ns0="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco">
<ns0:CharacterString>
some text

Some new data
</ns0:CharacterString>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this part of script that I've wrote for myself:

```
class Module():

def moduleLine(self):

    with open("/root/custom-nginx/nginx/debian/rules","r") as rules:

        lines = rules.readlines()

        for line in lines:

            if line.startswith("full_configure_flags"):
                full_index = str(line)

        findex = lines.index(full_index)

    for line in lines[int(findex)+1:]:

        if line.endswith(":= \\\n"):
            second_index = str(line)
            break
        else:
            continue

    sindex = lines.index(second_index)
    add_line = sindex-3

    rules.close()
    return add_line

def addModule(self,index):

    with open("/root/custom-nginx/nginx/debian/rules", "r") as file:
        data = file.readlines()
        data[index] = data[index] + "\t"*3 + "--add-module=$(MODULESDIR)/ngx_pagespeed \\" + "\n"
    file.close()
    with open("/root/custom-nginx/nginx/debian/rules","w") as file:
        file.writelines(data)
    file.close()
```

at the 'moduleLine' function it opens a file named rules and reads the line by `readlines()` (lines variable)

after that the if statement comes and checks the line if it matches the string that I want and findex contains the line number.

if you have an specific xml file and you know the line number you can use line number directly in your python code.

look at the `addModule` function, it appends the string of --add-module=$(MODULESDIR)/ngx_pagespeed \" + "\n" at the `data[index]` which index is the line number.

you can use this basis to append your string to your xml file.